# How can I add an app instance programmatically or declaratively?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, site-definition

I am currently working on a large deployment consisting of a large number of Site Collections with some custom SharePoint Apps (specifically custom ASP.Net High-Trust Provider Hosted Apps, but that shouldn't matter).

The site collections are all being provisioned from custom site definitions, so we have complete control over the provisioning process (be it adding features, modifying the onet.xml or even adding a managed code provisioning-provider if needed).

Does anyone know how to add an App Instance to a site programmatically and/or declaratively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the CSOM method [LoadAndInstallApp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.loadandinstallapp.aspx) which might help. Available via JavaScript and .NET.

Comment: Cheers mate :) the server-side API has the same call (as would be expected)
SPWeb.LoadAndInstallApp

Comment: I found the server side call a few days ago actually, and for some really odd reason I thought you were after a client side variant.